# why the value of a global variable in javascript is not getting changed in event listner whereas it does in normal functions?

Tags: javascript

I am stuck up in a strange scenario.

I want to change the value of a global javascript variable inside a listener function and access the changed value outside the listener function. But I am not able to get the updated value.

I have a html  element and a html  element

```js
    
    var abc=0;

    function actionClick(){
    abc=1;
    }
 
    function listner1(){
    console.log("abc:"+abc)
    }
```

```html
<button onclick=actionClick()>clickMe</button>

    <select onchange="listner1()">
        <option value="1">one</option>
        <option value="2">two</option> 
    </select>
```

order of action is

1. click the button
2. change the value in select element

   output is abc=0 whereas the output should have been abc=1

I therefore tried to do the same thing without the use of listener to check if I see the same behaviour if its not a listener. Here's my code for it:

```html
  <html>
    <body>
    </body>

    <script>
    var a=1;

    function demo(){
    a=2; 
    }

    alert("current value="+a);
    demo();
    alert("current value after call="+a);

    </script>
    </html>
```

Here what I observed is that I was getting the updated value after a call to function demo()

The two cases above are exactly the same in context to javascript except the listener part. Can anyone help me resolve this

Comment: Clearly there is a scope issue. Try and find out where abc exists, is it on `document` or is it on `window`? Could it be that one of them is changing the `document.abc` and the other is `window.abc`? Try doing `window.abc=0` and observe what happens and then do `window.abc=0`.

Comment: i was just added with snippet of your question.It working now where is  issue.

Comment: in snippet its running fine, not on my page. I tried with window.abc and the result is same.